# How to stop displacement of rest of the buttons while hovering over 1 button

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: #202124;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.Righty {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.Lefty {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.header_app {
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: grey;
  margin-top: -6px;
  padding-top: 0%;
}

.mainBody {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mainBody img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100px;
}

.search_input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-style: ridge;
  height: 48px;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.search_input input {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: medium;
}

.search-ico {
  color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.search_buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: rgb(244, 240, 240);
}

.search_buttons button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 28px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.search_buttons button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3c4043;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.search_buttons button :hover {
  border: 1px;
  padding: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  background-color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/practice.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Google Clone</title>
</head>
<!--Header section starts-->
<div class="header">
  <div class="Lefty">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Store</a>

  </div>

  <div class="Righty">
    <a href="#">Gmail</a>
    <a href="#">Images</a>
    <span class="material-icons header_app">
            apps
            </span>
    <span class="material-icons header_app">
                account_circle
                </span>

  </div>
</div>

<!--Header section ends-->

<!--Main Body section starts-->
<br>
<div class="mainBody">
  <img src="/graphics.html/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="google logo">


  <div class="search">
    <div class="search_input">
      <span class="material-icons search-ico">
            search
            </span>
      <input type="text" />
      <span class="material-icons search-ico">
                mic
                </span>
    </div>


    <div class="search_buttons">
      <button>
        <a href="#">Google Search</a>
    </button>

      <button>
        <a href="#">I'm Feeling Lucky</a>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Main Body section ends-->
</body>

</html>
```

When I use `hover` for buttons, hovering over 1 button makes the other buttons move too.
 [It's a clone of the Google Search page, made using HTML and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjCVi.png)

When I hover over the "Google search" button, the "I'm feeling lucky" button next to it moves towards the left.

I have added the code but the problem is just with the Google Search and I'm feeling lucky buttons

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! :) Can you share your code? Please check out this link with some more info on how to best ask clear questions: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Remove the space in `.search_buttons button :hover {..}` like `.search_buttons button:hover{..}`, as you want to 'hover' the button, not the `<a>`.  Also remove the `margin/padding: inherit` in that rule, no need to 'inherit' anything.

Comment: i did the same. but the button next to that is still moving but less than before